# How to use module.exports correctly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I have an index.js file with a module.export which looks as follows :

```
var databaseInstance, collection;

app.listen(3000, () => {
    MongoClient.connect(CONNECTION_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, (error, client) => {
        if(error) {
            console.log(error)
            throw error;
        }
        databaseInstance = client.db(DATABASE_NAME);
        collection = databaseInstance.collection("Users");
    });
});

function GetDatabaseInstance() {

  if (!databaseInstance) {
    console.error("databaseInstance has not been set");
  } else {
    return databaseInstance;
  }
}


 module.exports = {
    GetDatabaseInstance: function() {
     return GetDatabaseInstance(); 
   }

 };
```

CONNECTION_URL and DATABASE_NAME are hardcoded to values from MongoDB's Atlas. I have verified that databaseInstance is not undefined.

Now I want to be able to use the value of databaseInstance in another file user-ctrl.js which is a controller file. I am importing the index.js as follows :

```
const Index =  require('../index.js')
```

I am trying to use the function GetDatabaseInstance() in this file so I can access the value of databaseInstance in it. I am doing it as follows :

```
var database = Index.GetDatabaseInstance()
```

However I am getting the error : UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Index.GetDatabaseInstance is not a function

What am I doing wrong here? Please help!

Comment: Can you please check if there is not any `module.exports`  statement in this file after this line. Because if this is express main file, then it will have `module.exports = app;` at the end.

Comment: can you post the whole content of `index.js`?

Answer (score 0):

I exported the function GetDatabaseInstance in index.js as follows :

```
exports.GetDatabaseInstance = GetDatabaseInstance;
```

I imported the index.js file in another file as follows :

```
const index =  require('../index')
```

Then I used this import to get the database instance from the index file and query it to get my documents from MongoDB :

```
var database = index.GetDatabaseInstance() //retrieve the database instance

if(database !== undefined)
var collection = await database.collection("YOUR_COLLECTION_NAME") //retrieve the collection

if(collection !== undefined)
collection.find({"userName" : "USER_NAME"}).toArray((err, user) => { //query the MongoDB collection 
...
})
```